Best database solution for high volume tables / data indexing (snapshots) [PostgreSQL]
My problem at the moment, is that I need to index/save snapshots of some data every x minutes, so every x minutes I am inserting around 500k new rows, into a table, which each one represents a snapshot of an account.
My general problem is that this creates around 100Gb of new data per day at the moment, what is the best way to compress this, without increasing the time spent on querying.
Is TimescaleDB a nice solution, even though isn't a time-series based table?

What problem are you trying to solve here?...disk space consumption?

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! The table's DDL would be a nice-to-have for this question! A columnar solution could work well, especially if there are no (few?) updates, as with time-series data!

You have different options to handle it:

Timescale could be a good option. Using hypertables you can automatically manage partitions and compression.

PostgreSQL is also a solid choice but may require more manual intervention to manage partitioning and may not handle the high insert rate as efficiently as other options.

ClickHouse could be an alternative if your workload is read-heavy too. Its columnar storage and compression algorithms should handle large datasets correctly.


I'd recommend testing these options to see which one works better for your workload.
